# Postgresql, regex pattern match in "where"

Tags: string, postgresql

One table column is a string that contains multiple substrings separated by delimiter character the pipe char (|), like this "aa-a|aa-a-a|a-a|aa", the delimiter character cannot be the leading and ending char of the column string. And the match check is in "where", when match then the row is selected. Actually it's a search, pass in substring such as "aa-a" and search for all rows that has the "aa-a" as a full substring, the "aa-a-a" should not be a match. Another case also need to be considered when there is only one substring and no delimiter. Something like this:

```
Select * from tb where REGEX_FUNC(tb.col_1, "pattern")>0
```

in which the "pattern" might be like "^aa-a$" (1) what the REGEX_FUNC should be, need to create my own? (2) what the "pattern" should be?

Comment: you shouldn't be storing delimited values like that to begin with.

Comment: so you mean all substrings should be stored separately into cells instead of being combined into one cell? or any other solution?

Comment: Each value should most probably be a _row_ in a separate table. That's a classical example of a one-to-many relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a regex match.

You can convert the delimited value into an array, then check the array if it matches your comparison value:

```
where 'aa-a' = any(string_to_array(col1, '|'))
```